# mysql TIME_WAIT ; too many connections problem

Tags: mysql

When i was checking for mysql load time on site. i got result showing connections as TIME_WAIT. Even though i close connection on every page.  Sometimes the site doesnt load saying too many connections. What  could be solution to this problem?

Thanks in Advance for any replies or suggestions

Comment: Must be some connection leak in some flow path or may be php throwing errors before mysql_close is called. If you are using mod_php consider persistent connections http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

Comment: Its just simple  select query and I am using mysql_connect() and mysql_close() functions. i guess persistent  connections create problems, they stay sometimes in sleep mode even when they are closed

Answer (score 7):

If a client connects to a MySQL-Server, it usually opens a local port, example:

```
 localhost:12345 -> mysqlserver:3306
```

If the client closes the connection, the client gets a TIME_WAIT. Due to TCP routing, a packet might arrive late on the temporary port. A connection in TIME_WAIT just discards these packets. Without a TIME_WAIT, the local port might be reused for another connection and might receive packets from a former connection.

On an high frequent application on the web which opens a mysql-connection per request, a high amount of TIME_WAIT connections is expectable. There is nothing wrong with it.

Problems can occur, if your local port range is too low, so you cannot open outgoing connections any more. The usual timeout is set to 60 seconds. So a problem can already occur on more than 400 requests per second on low ranges.

**Check:**

To check the amount of TIME_WAIT, you can use the following command:

```
$ cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 341
TCP: inuse 12 orphan 0 tw 33365 alloc 23 mem 16
UDP: inuse 9 mem 2
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

The value after "tw", in this case 33365, shows the amount of TIME_WAIT.

**Solutions:**

a. TIME_WAIT tuning (Linux based OS examples):

Reduce the timeout for TIME_WAIT:

```
# small values are ok, if your mysql server is in the same local network
echo 15 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

Increase the port range for local ports:

```
# check, what you highest listening ports are, before setting this
echo 15000 65000 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

The settings `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse` might be interesting, too. (But we experienced strange side effects with these settings, so better avoid them. More informations in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426253/tcp-tw-reuse-vs-tcp-tw-recycle-which-to-use-or-both))

b. Persistent Connections

Some programming languages and libraries support persistent connections. Another solution might be using a locally installed proxy like "ProxySQL". This reduces the amount of new and closed connections.

Comment: _If the client closes the connection, you get a TIME_WAIT._ who is "you" referring to in this statement? And if it is referring to 'mysqlserver' then this statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting alot of TIME_WAIT connections on the Mysql Server then that means that Mysql server is closing the connection.  The most likely case in this instance would be that  a host or several hosts got on a block list.  You can clear this by running

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

to get a list of the number of connections you have per ip run,

```
 netstat -nat | awk {'print $5'} | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

you can also confirm this is happening by going to one of your clients that is having trouble connecting and telnet to port 3306.  It will thow a message with something like,

```
telnet mysqlserver 3306
Trying 192.168.1.102...
Connected to mysqlserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
sHost 'clienthost.local' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Zimbabao suggested in the comment, debug your code for any potential errors that may halt the execution of closing the Mysql connection.

If nothing works, check your my.cnf for a system variable called `wait_timeout`. If its not present add it to the section `[mysqld]` and restart your Mysql server.

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 3600
```

Its the number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it. Further information can be found http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Tune the figure 3600 (1 hour) to your requirements.

HTH

Comment: i had tried checking by putting the condition <?php  if(mysql_close($conn)) echo "connection closed"; ?> It prints back "connection closed".  is there any explicit close connection in php to close  db connection?